# How to rewrite [--convert an array into multiple objects-] as shown below to make it work in IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

This section can be executed normally in chrome, but it is wrong in IE

The desired effect is:

```
//[arr]is a lot of imges urls
<ul>
<li><img src=[arr]></li>
<li><img src=[arr]></li>
...
</ul>
```

Looking for an alternative replace the code below:

```js
//Not surport IE
//-----------------------------------------------
const arrayToHtmlList = (arr, listID) =>
arr.map(item => (document.querySelector('#' + listID).innerHTML += `<li><img class=image-of-list 
src=${item}></li>`));
arrayToHtmlList(imgSrcs, 'x2');  
//-----------------------------------------------
```

//-----------------------------------------------

Comment: IE won't be able to run your code, as it uses some recent ecmascript syntax (such as `=>`). Rewrite your code with classic functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arrayToHtmlList = function  (arr, listID) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
        var el = document.getElementById(listID);
        el.innerHTML+= '<li><img class=image-of-list src="' + item + '"></li>';
        return el;
   });
};
arrayToHtmlList(imgSrcs, 'x2');
```

Comment: just some other ```and`${item}` ,can this be replaced?

Comment: el.innerHTML  += '<li><img class=image-of-list 
  src="' + item+ '"></li>'

Comment: Useful! It achieved. thanks~ Not a professional code worker, just for personal websites, so in your opinion it is a small problem, but it is a big problem for me 